# In R Shiny, why do my functions not work when using the render UI function but work fine when not using render UI?

Tags: r, shiny

When running the first "almost MWE" code immediately below, which uses conditional panels and a "renderUI" function in the server section, it only runs correctly when I comment out the 3rd line from the bottom, `observeEvent(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()),{yield_vector.R <<- unique(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()))})`. If I run the code with this line activated, it crashes and I get the error message `Error in [: subscript out of bounds` which per my research means it is trying to access an array out of its boundary.

```
library(shiny); library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

# --- Initial values for performance vectors input matrix
m2 <- function(x) {matrix(c(1,1), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Y (period)", "Z (variable)")))}

# --- MatrixInput function to use for performance vector
matrix2.input <- function(x) {matrixInput(
    x,
    value = {m2()},
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")} # close function

# --- Auto-correct user inputs into column Y of the input matrix
matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- x                                # Assign input values to dummy matrix a
  a[,1][a[,1]>y] <- y                   # Assign value of period X to instances where input period "Y" > periods to model X
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])           # Computes differences between successive row values (negative value is a problem)
  b[b<=0] <- NA                         # Any row value differences <= 0 are assigned NA
  b <- c(1,b)                           # Creates new column of row value differences & assigns value of 1 to first row, pushes rest of values down 1 field
  a <- cbind(a,b)                       # Adds new columns to input matrix values for NA flags
  a <- na.omit(a)                       # Deletes any rows with element NA
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]             # Deletes NA flag columns
  return(a)}

# --- Vector function interpolates & spreads input across even time horizon
vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)                                                     # Generates NA numbering X periods
  a[Y] <- Z                                                           # Places each variable Z in position indicated by its respective period Y
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]                                   # If 1st period (Y) > 1, applies that variable Z to all periods <= Y
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}                         # Applies value of 0 to all periods in X after the greatest period specified in Y, if there are any
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y    # The only NA's remaining, after all of the above, are periods to interpolate. This code interpolates
  b <- seq(1:X)                                                       # Creates a column for number of X periods
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)                                       # Merges b and a into data frame, assigns column header labels of X and Z
  return(c)}

# --- Runs vector through matrix.validate to output clean vector data
vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(y,x)[,1],matrix.validate(y,x)[,2])}

###########################################################################################################
ui <- 
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1",
                     numericInput("begin.bal","Beginning balance:",value=100000,step=1000),
                     sliderInput("periods", "Number of periods to model:",min=1,max=120,value=60),
                     h5("Vectorize performance variable:"), 
                     
                     # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors --->
                     useShinyjs(),
                     actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn', 'Show'), 
                     actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn', 'Hide'), 
                     uiOutput("Vectors")),
    
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                     selectInput("dataset", "select the desired dataset", 
                                 choices=ls('package:datasets'), 
                                 selected = "")), 
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3",uiOutput("varx"),uiOutput("vary"))
  ), # close sidebar panel
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Dynamic", value=1,
          helpText("Pending...")),
      tabPanel("Data", value=2, 
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==1", verbatimTextOutput("dat")),
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==2", verbatimTextOutput("struct")),
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))),
      tabPanel("Plot", value=3, plotOutput("plot")), 
      
      id = "tabselected"
    ) # close tabset panel
  ) # close main panel
) # close page with sidebar

 server <- function(input,output)({

# --- Set reactive input variables 
 periods       <-  reactive(input$periods)
 yield_input   <-  reactive(input$yield_input)
 
# --- Start of action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors
 output$Vectors <- renderUI({
   req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)
    tagList(
      fluidRow(       
        actionButton("explain4", "Gross yield >>",icon=icon("info-circle"),
                     style ="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;width: 24.5vw;margin-top:5px;")),
      fluidRow(style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px",  
                     matrix2.input("yield_input"))
    ) # close tag list    
  }) # close render UI
   
observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})

# --- Captures inputs and outputs as global variables
  observeEvent(periods(), {periods.R <<- unique(periods())})
  observeEvent(yield_input(), {yield_input.R <<- unique(yield_input())})
  observeEvent(matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()), {yield_validate.R <<- unique(matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()))})
  #observeEvent(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()),{yield_vector.R <<- unique(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()))})

}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, the below almost-MWE code, without using renderUI and conditional panels, runs the same functions just fine. There´s a problem with my use of renderUI is my guess in the above code. What can be causing this problem?

(Note that when running and manually inputting into the matrix, you have to click first on the right column and next on the left column of the input matrix. This is a minor bug with shinyMatrix which I have a fix for).

These functions basically extend and interpolate user data inputs into the matrix. Here´s that working code that the above is based off of:

```
library(shiny); library(shinyMatrix)

# --- Set initial values for performance vectors input matrix
m2 <- function(x) {matrix(c(1,1), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Y (period)", "Z (variable)")))} 

# --- matrixInput function
matrix2.input <- function(x) {
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = {m2()},
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

# --- Auto-correct user inputs into column Y of the input matrix
matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- x                                # Assign input values to dummy matrix a
  a[,1][a[,1]>y] <- y                   # Assign value of period X to instances where input period "Y" > periods to model X
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])           # Computes differences between successive row values (negative value is a problem)
  b[b<=0] <- NA                         # Any row value differences <= 0 are assigned NA
  b <- c(1,b)                           # Creates new column of row value differences & assigns value of 1 to first row, pushes rest of values down 1 field
  a <- cbind(a,b)                       # Adds new columns to input matrix values for NA flags
  a <- na.omit(a)                       # Deletes any rows with element NA
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]             # Deletes NA flag columns
  return(a)}

# --- Vector function interpolates & spreads input across even time horizon
vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)                                                     # Generates NA numbering X periods
  a[Y] <- Z                                                           # Places each variable Z in position indicated by its respective period Y
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]                                   # If 1st period (Y) > 1, applies that variable Z to all periods <= Y
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}                         # Applies value of 0 to all periods in X after the greatest period specified in Y, if there are any
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)], seq_along(a))$y   # The only NAÃÂ´s remaining, after all of the above, are periods to interpolate. This code interpolates
  b <- seq(1:X)                                                       # Creates a column for number of X periods
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)                                       # Merges b and a into data frame, assigns column header labels of X and Z
  return(c)}

# --- Runs vector through matrix.validate to output clean vector data
vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(y,x)[,1],matrix.validate(y,x)[,2])}

#######################################################################################################

ui <- fluidPage(style = "margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px",
    column(3, 
        fluidRow(
             sliderInput("periods", "Nbr of Periods:",min = 1, max = 120, value = 60)),
      
        # --- Action button and matrix input for yield
        fluidRow(style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px",  
             matrix2.input("yield_input")),
      ), # close column
      
      column(9,style = "text-align:center",plotOutput("graph1"),
    ) # close column
  )  # fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {

  # --- Set reactive input variables
  periods       <-  reactive(input$periods)
  yield_input   <-  reactive(input$yield_input)

  # --- Yield plot
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    plot({vector.final(periods(),yield_input())},
      type="b",main='Gross yield vector',xlab='X (time horizon)',ylab = 'Z (yield in period X)')})
  
  # --- Captures inputs and outputs as global variables
  observeEvent(periods(), {periods.R <<- unique(periods())})
  observeEvent(yield_input(), {yield_input.R <<- unique(yield_input())})
  observeEvent(matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()), {yield_validate.R <<- unique(matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()))})
  observeEvent(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()),{yield_vector.R <<- unique(vector.final(periods(),yield_input()))})
    
} # closes server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment. An alternative solution is to replace commented out line in original MWE, without using `req` function (`req` caused me problems later because it didn't address a core issue with using the defined functions at the top of the MWE, it allowed the user to skip over situations where there are mis-matches in matrix dimensions), with the following line of code:

```
observeEvent(vector.final(periods(),matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods())),{yield_vector.R <<- vector.final(periods(),matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()))})
```

Another task of mine will be to simplify those functions!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line you commented out with this

```
oe <- reactive({
  req(periods(), yield_input())
  vector.final(periods(), yield_input())
})
observeEvent(oe(), {
  yield_vector.R <<- unique(oe())
})
```

Not sure what the apps is doing, but the error is coming from the function `vector.final` being called with a NULL argument. The `req` call will ensure they are populated before the `observeEvent` will trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I learned from it. Also thanks for not getting bogged down with that the functions are supposed to be doing (they do work as intended) and why I bother with setting the outputs as global variables! I'm still not sure why this problem only cropped up when converting from simpler form to conditional panels/UI but it'll probably come clear to me as I get more experience with renderUI/conditionals

Comment: Use of  req caused problems later because it didn't address an issue with using the defined functions at the top of MWE. I created those functions & in a few weeks forgot how they work. So I deconstructed to understand again. So a solution to my original problem, without using req (which glosses over the situation where there are mis-matches in dimensions of matrices), is to replace the commented out code above with: observeEvent(vector.final(periods(),matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods())),{yield_vector.R <<- vector.final(periods(),matrix.validate(yield_input(),periods()))})